# Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationManager' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: asp.net-identity

I am trying to implement ASP.NET Identity 2.0. I have created a MVC4 project in VS 2012 and installed ASP.NET Identity 2.0 packages using Nu Get command. I am getting compile error message 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationManager' is inaccessible due to its protection level'with following code.

Getting compile error because AuthenticationManager is a internal class in assembly EntityFramework.dll.
So can I derive a class from AuthenticationManager and call public methods SignIn() and SignOut().

There is a class AuthenticationManagerExtensions in same assembly. How can I use this for SignIn and SignOut?

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;

    private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(
           user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(
           new AuthenticationProperties()
           {
               IsPersistent = isPersistent
           }, identity);
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The AuthenticationManager used here is the Authentication object of the current Owin context. The problem is resolved by adding following property in same class.

```
    private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
    }
```